# Border color not changing JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".red").addClass("selected");
});
```

```css
.selected {
  border-color: black;
}

.red {
  border: 4px solid red;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.colourbox {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://bernii.github.io/gauge.js/dist/gauge.min.js"></script>
<script src="actions.js"></script>
<div class=" red colourbox">
</div>
```

> Problem

On running the **HTML** file the border around the divison doesn't remain black and border-color: black is crossed out in chrome's developer tools

> How do I change the border colour on adding the selected class ?

Comment: Please share the code in `jsfiddle`.

Comment: Do you want to change border-color on load?

Comment: this is caused by order of your css, as your `.red` style is above `.selected` it selects red by default and even when you add .select it still selects red first.. move your .selected above the .red and it should work

Comment: Made it a fiddle and edited his post. He probably doesn't have a jquery reference. It works lol

Comment: No i do have it

Comment: You might want to put that selected rule below the `red` class. The red class will always override it. It wasn't above when I edited it before it got overridden by your change OP

Comment: @IamCavic Even after pushing `.selected` above ,no change ,no effect

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WggmbN
codepen of your code and its working 
you might forget to add jquery library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put `selected` below `red` to avoid having the `red` ruleset override `selected`'s `border-color` property.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {            
  $(".red").addClass("selected");     
});
```

```css
.red {
  border: 4px solid red ;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
.colourbox {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
.selected {
  border-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="red colourbox"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

You can put the `.selected` at the bottom of `.red` so that it will override the `.red` styles. Or use the nesting like I did. That will help you

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".red").addClass("selected");  
});
```

```css
.red {
    border: 4px solid red ;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
.red.selected {
    border-color: black;
}

.colourbox {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="red colourbox"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your requirements. What you need to ask yourself is:

*Do I always need a black border in combination with a red square?*

If that is the case, use this solution. Do not define `.selected` but `.red.selected`. In that case the location does not matter.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".red").addClass("selected");
});
```

```css
.red.selected {
  border-color: black;
}

.red {
  border: 4px solid red;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.colourbox {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="red colourbox">
</div>
```

If you want to apply the black border independently, you need to structure your code as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".square").toggleClass("red selected");
});
```

```css
.square {
  background-color: red;
}

.red {
  border: 4px solid red;
}

.colourbox {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}

.selected {
  border: 4px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="square colourbox red">
</div>
```